Color different curves on a graph
How can I give color to each curve associated with each value that the parameter $a$ takes in a list? Initially I did the following
g[x_, b_] := x^2 + b;
a = List[-10, 1, 10];
Plot[g[x, a], {x, 2, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 40}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Blue}]

but what I get is

I would like a different color for each curve. Could someone guide me please?

g[x, a] // Evaluate

g[x_, b_] := x^2 + b;

a = List[-10, 1, 10];

You have to Evaluate
Plot[Evaluate @ g[x, a], {x, 2, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 PlotRange -> {0, 40}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Blue}]


